# Has anyone else encountered the issue with the Limit Rotation bone constraint?

Tags: rigging, armature, geometry, pose-mode, bone.constraints

I'm having an issue with my transform constraints. It seems that when I apply a Limit Rotation constraint, the bone completely ignores it.

*The Issue*
https://youtu.be/LohLP-KnWrY

**Attempted solutions:**

- Restarting Blender
- Reloading the file
- Restarting computer
- Looking online for similar issues (None relative to the issue found.)

If you have any solution or work-around it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You're adding an object constraint in your video, not a bone constraint.  Bone constraints are a different tab.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found out the issue, I was listing the constraint under "Object Constraints" instead of "Bone Constraints".